# Formatting numerical output in bash to have exactly 4 decimal places

Tags: bash, printf, numeric-data

I have a command that outputs a number to a log file, and I don't like the way it looks when the number changes the number of decimal places because it ruins the alignment and makes everything look messy. How do I force the output to have the same number of decimal places each time?

ex:

```
531.125
531.4561
531.3518
531.2
```

should be:

```
531.1250
531.4561
531.3518
531.2000
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you can modify or configure the mysterious *command* to do what you want then do it; else [man 1 printf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/printf.1.html). What has poor Bash to do with what this mysterious *command* outputs?

Comment: my understanding is that I can use the command `printf "%d.4" 531.2` to restrict the decimal place, but when I do that it says `bash: printf: 531.2: invalid number`

Comment: what if the integer part will be less than 3 places, like `50.1111` ? That will also *ruin the alignment*

Comment: The number is a status indicator that should never go above 540 or below 520. It is unlikely that the integer part will be a problem. Thanks though!!!

Comment: @sam, show how that command getting run and output a number to logfile (pipeline)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In bash printf is able to use the `%f` format

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in 531.125 531.4561 531.3518 531.2; do
    printf "%8.4f\n" "$a"
done
```

Executed gives:

```
531.1250
531.4561
531.3518
531.2000
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that I needed to use f instead of d in the printf formatting argument

Comment: @Arrow. I fixed the `printf` line so your sample code works.  You forgot the `$a`

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Ooops, nice of you to edit it, thanks. I Just had to add "quote your var expansions"

Comment: @Arrow.   No need for quotes in this particular case

Comment: In this particular case, 3.4 works, but in the more-general case, I think you'd want 8.4 (full width is 8, with 4 places of precision).

Comment: @JeffSchaller That's correct, answer edited.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Sure they are a "good company" for general cases.